# Quartz.NET setting MisfireInstruction

Tags: c#, sql, scheduler, quartz.net, quartz.net-2.0

I'm working in C# using Quartz.NET and am having problems setting the misfire instruction on a CronTrigger.  I'm running an SQL backend with the Quartz DB installed.  I have the following code which works fine for creating a job and running a scheduler.

```
IScheduler _scheduler;
IJobDetail job;
ISchedulerFactory sFactory;
ICronTrigger trig;

sFactory = new StdSchedulerFactory();

_scheduler = sFactory.GetScheduler();
_scheduler.Start();

job = JobBuilder.Create<Test>().WithIdentity("testJob", "testGroup").Build();
trig = (ICronTrigger) TriggerBuilder.Create().WithIdentity("testTrigger", "testGroup").WithCronSchedule("0/10 * * * * ?").Build(); int i = trig.MisfireInstruction;

_scheduler.ScheduleJob(job, trig);
```

The only misfireinstruction I can access is `trig.MisfireInstruction` which is an int, and I can't set it.
There are also some functions beginning `WithMisfireHandlingInstruction` in CronScheduleBuilder.

Comment: `MisfireInstruction.CronTrigger.FireOnceNow` may be what I'm looking for...?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your trigger creation should be like this:

```
trig = (ICronTrigger)TriggerBuilder
       .Create()
       .WithIdentity("testTrigger", "testGroup")
       .WithCronSchedule("0/10 * * * * ?", x => x.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed())
       .Build();
```

you can use these options:

- WithMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing
- WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed
- WithMisfireHandlingInstructionIgnoreMisfires

You can find a good explanation [here](https://dzone.com/articles/quartz-scheduler-misfire).

Comment: Glad I've helped. You can always up-vote me in the future :-) Cheers.

Comment: the link is broken:(

Comment: @stambikk: fixed.