# Quartz.net - misfire instructions don't work

Tags: c#, .net, cron, quartz.net

I am using quartz.net with CRON scheduling.
I set misfire instruction to : fire and proceed:

```
 trigger = Quartz.TriggerBuilder.Create()
                       .WithIdentity(jobData.JobId, jobData.ClientApplicationId.ToString())//.WithCronSchedule(scheduleInfo.CronExpression, WithMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing())
                        .WithSchedule(Quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.CronSchedule(new Quartz.CronExpression(scheduleInfo.CronExpression)).WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed())//.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionDoNothing())  ///.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed()
                       .StartAt(DateTime.Now).ForJob(iJobDetail)
                       .Build();
```

From what I read, if a trigger was missed , it should fire as soon as the scheduler is up
(one time maximum, even if the job was suppose to run many times).

For some reason when I test it, the job is never triggered.
Say I have a job that should run every hour starting from 4:00.
I turn on the scheduler at 7:30 , I don't get any trigger fires - until 8:00.
misfireThreshold is set to (60000) - one minute.

The job is statefuul and does not allow concurrent runs.
I am using a persistent store (AdoJobStore) -saving the schedules to the MSSQL DB.

Any idea why the trigger isn't firing on schedule activation?

Comment: Are you using a persistent job store? Next fire time is calculated when job is added and scheduler started, with RAMJobstore this information is lost on shutdown.

Comment: Yes, that's a very important thing - I'm using A Dateabase and not RAM store, I will add it to my question. thanks

Comment: And also which version? Make sure you are running the latest version.

Comment: Version is 2.1.2 , I will try to update. In the documentation I couldn't find a relevant bug fix, but I hope the upgrade will help. Thanks

Comment: I've updated to version 2.2.1 but still get the same problem. Any idea how to fix it or at least analyze it? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try the code below instead. Make sure to replace {YourCronExpressionString} with your own cron expression.

```
trigger = Quartz.TriggerBuilder.Create()
                   .WithIdentity(jobData.JobId, jobData.ClientApplicationId.ToString())
                   .WithCronSchedule("{YourCronExpressionString}", x => x.WithMisfireHandlingInstructionFireAndProceed())
                   .StartAt(DateTime.Now).ForJob(iJobDetail)
                   .Build();
```

Source: [Quartz.NET setting MisfireInstruction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13588627/quartz-net-setting-misfireinstruction)

Answer (score -2):

try to use PauseJob(jobKey) method to missfire

use ResumeJob(jobKey) method to trigger it again

for example:

set cronexpression:every 4 hours

at 7:30 , call pauseJob method

and at 8:01,call resumeJob method

the job at 8:00 will be refire

Comment: Is this for testing purpose? I test by closing the sceduler , changing the time of my computer and than open the scheduler again